# Python: When to return a response code?

Tags: rest, flask, python-3.5, gevent

I have an API that accepts a user input and does lots of processing on the back. My question is, should I return a response code (200) after input validation or should I wait until the input processing (saving to mysql, formatting the input, saving to redis, etc) has ended?

Sample code:

```
# Should I wait for the greenlets to finish processing - which might take a long time?
@app.route('/messages', methods=['POST'])
def send_message():
    user_input = flask.request.form.get('user_input')

    if user_is_valid() and user_input_is_valid(user_input):
        process_input = [gevent.spawn(format_input_and_save_to_mysql, user_input),
                         gevent.spawn(format_input_and_save_to_redis, user_input)]
        gevent.join_all(process_input)
        return 'Processing done', 200

    return 'Unauthorized', 401

# Or should I return immediately even though the processing is still being done?
@app.route('/messages', methods=['POST'])
def send_message():
    user_input = flask.request.form.get('user_input')

    if user_is_valid() and user_input_is_valid(user_input):
        gevent.spawn(format_input_and_save_to_mysql, user_input)
        gevent.spawn(format_input_and_save_to_redis, user_input)
        return 'Processing done', 200

    return 'Unauthorized', 401
```

Answer (score 1):

You should think about what returning a response means: When the browser receives a response from the server the browser thinks that his request is done, redirected or failed somehow.

Due to that you should think about this for every specific case. If you need the results of the request handling at the end of all your tasks, you might wait for all the procedures to be completed and return the result or a suitable status code if one of those sub-task fails.

However, if those tasks are really long-running (like several seconds) you might get in trouble because of request timeouts. If so, there a several techniques to solve that issue like using interval polling, long-polling or websockets.

Every kind of polling would be implemented in the frontend which means that the browser needs to ask the server for new content or data. So you would return a response from the server when the long-running tasks are started. Analyzing this response in the browser would start polling against a given API endpoint. Based on the progress of the long-running tasks you might return a given status or the processed data and stop polling. If the processes are not done you could return something like a "still running" status and poll again. So polling would lead to several requests from the browser and appropriate responses from the server.

Websockets in contrast offer real-time communication between server and browser since both browser and server are able to raise so called events on the websockets connection.

At the end of the day, you need to decide what you really need. Websockets are really great but IMHO a bit tricky to handle if you are a beginner. However, there is an example about how to [implement websockets using Flask and gevent](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent). However, there is one big thing you need to keep in mind. When requesting the progress of those server tasks either by polling or by websockets you need to make sure to have the possibility to get a status or progress message from those tasks which is a totally different thing to solve. If you need a starting point for this, I would suggest having a look at a task queue, e.g. [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html).